# Объясните что я делаю не так с связный списком python

Tags: python, linked-list

я новичок и решил выполнить свою первую задачу на связный список [вот она](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/description/).
Я сначала решил посмотреть как оно работает и создать новый список из списка, который даётся в задаче, но мне выпадает ошибка когда я вызываю значение(res.val)  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'.
Но если просто вывести переменную res, то она показывает полную структуру списка и я не понимаю, что не так.
Вот что выведет если просто вызвать переменную:

```
ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}}
```

```
res = ListNode(l1.val)
print(res.val, res.next)
res.next = l1.next
print(res.val, res.next)
res = res.next
print(res.val)
```

Я пробовал разные варианты но у меня не получается, подскажите, что упускаю

Comment: Перенесите текст задачи в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Так, я пофиксил, можно расходиться. Я не совсем понимаю почему так проиходит, но вот так оно работает

```
res = ListNode(2)
res.next = ListNode(4)
res.next.next = ListNode(3)
```